# Call require API18(current min is 8)?

Tags: android, facebook, android-notifications

I write a simple app that if when I press the button a facebook notification set one variable to a specific values, When I run this code on my phone the app go on crash, and before that  I see one error in this line (sbn.getPackageName().contains("com.facebook.katana") telling me that API 18 is required, but I've already added it in the manifest!
I don't know if this can help, but I'm using Android Studio!

**In the MainActivity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static int i=0;

    private  StatusBarNotification sbn;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Button b1,b2,b3,b4;
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);


       b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {


                        if(sbn.getPackageName().contains("com.facebook.katana")) {
                            i = 1;
                            Toast msg;
                            msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    "IT'S GREEEEEN!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            msg.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

**In the AndroidManifest file**

```
<uses-sdk
                android:minSdkVersion="18"
                android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

**Logcat**

```
05-01 15:43:32.914  30717-30717/com.example.myapplication.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-01 15:43:32.914  30717-30717/com.example.myapplication.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4160cba8)
05-01 15:43:32.914  30717-30717/com.example.myapplication.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication.app, PID: 30717
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.myapplication.app.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is ur Phone Version ? plus use Emulator with Version 19 to check if it works

Comment: please post a full stack trace from Logcat

Comment: Are you using gradle?

Comment: Yes,sorry while I was doing the app forgot to respond!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is that `sbn` is null, in your `onClick`

You need to get the list of notification with `NotificationListenerService`, before accessing it.

check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

```
(sbn.getPackageName().contains("com.facebook.katana") telling me that API 18 is required
```

You need to change `minSdkVersion 18` in `gradle build config`

Answer (score 0):

`Android Studio` does not read the minimum SDK level from `AndroidManifest.xml` file. It reads it from `build.gradle` file. Your `build.gradle` file should contain these lines below:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 18
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because `sbn` variable is only declared and never initialized.

That means you will have a `NullPointerException` when using it.